# Macromedia Dreamweaver 4 work with Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: dreamweaver, windows-7-x64

I am thinking of putting an older version of DW (Macromedia DW4) on my computer at work but locating it around the house will be challenging so I would like to know if it will work on my Windows 7 OS before trying to track it down.

Has anyone tried to install this?

I know it does not list Windows 7 as one of the compatible OSs but that doesn't mean it won't actually work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine. If it gives you a minor snag you can always run the installation and the program in "Compatibility Mode" for an older OS. Good luck!